# How can one delete Skype-preview chat history for all contacts (or just a single contact)?

Tags: skype

How can one delete chat history for all contacts (or a single one of them) in Win10's [Skype-preview](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34586/what-is-skype-preview-in-windows-10) software?

Thank you,

Comment: Your chat history is stored server side, the only way to wipe your history, is to clear each individual history for each user.  Using the desktop Skype client how you do this is obvious, I suggest you use that, instead of the Skype Preview UWP version for the time being.

Comment: See the article [How to delete chat history of a particular user/contact in Skype](http://subharanjan.com/how-to-delete-chat-history-of-a-particular-usercontact-in-skype-solved/) which use SQLite Browser to manipulate the file `main.db`. I don't know if this works with Skype-preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete history functionality is missing in the current version. At the moment, you can clean up your recent list by hiding conversations.

Steps:

```
 1. Right click on conversation 
 2. Choose Hide Conversation
```

Simple solution for now.

P.S. Hopefully, in the future updates you can see some options kind of *History delete*.

Answer (score 1):

The Bad news is you can't delete it: https://community.skype.com/t5/Preview-on-Windows-10/How-to-delete-conversations-in-Skype-Preview/td-p/4448492

Microsoft is still working on it...

Workaround: 
-Delete the messages from the conversation: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34636/how-do-i-delete-instant-messages-in-skype

Comment: From your 2nd link: "Deleting a conversation is not currently supported on Skype for Windows desktop, or Skype Preview for Windows 10."

Comment: Nice catch, I mixed it with the remove message. I think there was a "Downgrade and delete" workaround somewhere but that sounded way too ludicrous at the time. Not so any more. @harrymc, thanks anyway.